# Pulling two objects from two separate arrays in a foreach

Tags: php

I'm sure I'm over-thinking this, any help to steer me straight is appreciated.  I need to pull two array variables and place them in a link so that I can I can apply them to another form in order to change their respective arrays (these links are used to pull recipient names and their uid values that are stored in a session arrays.)  So, in my foreach, the "$contactlistunique as $rec" line seems to work fine in order to pull the username, but now I need to figure out a way to pull the uid object.  Foreach operations don't allow for multiple conditions, so what's the smartest way to do this?

```
<?php
$contactlistuidunique = array_unique($_SESSION['recipientlist']);
$contactlistunique = array_unique($_SESSION['contactlist']);
foreach ($contactlistunique as $rec)
    {
    echo "<font color=#808080><a href='removecontact.php?contact=$recuid&recipient=$rec' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>
    <font color=#808080>" . $rec . "</a></font>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: have you tried a for loop ?

Comment: if you use a for loop, you can create a variable for each (or access them directly) using $contactlistuidunique[$i] where $i is your incrementer.

Comment: This isn't really possible without some sort of shared key between them.  Supposedly entries in your `$contactlistunique` correspond to entries in your `$contactlistuidunique` array.  How can you pull corresponding data without some sort of reference?  If you already have one, then there ya go you just answered your own question.  If not, then you should create one.

Comment: How does recipientlist and contact list have some mapping to each other?

Comment: Both arrays correspond to each other via index, They both share the same index values.  Frankly, I'm not sure if I'm approaching this the right way.  I guess the logic is that if they share the same index, I can pull that value once and then apply a operation to remove that entry in both arrays.  I guess, then, how would I pull the index value for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it though the question is not much clear to me

```
<?php
$contactlistuidunique = array_unique($_SESSION['recipientlist']);
$contactlistunique = array_unique($_SESSION['contactlist']);
foreach ($contactlistunique as $key=>$rec)
{
    echo "<font color=#808080><a href='removecontact.php?contact=".$contactlistuidunique[$key]."&recipient=$rec' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>
    <font color=#808080>" . $rec . "</a></font>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I would add an `if(isset($contactlistuidunique[$key]))` for sanity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Based on you comments, I advice you not to use array_unique, but do the following:

```
<?php
$isBefore = array();
foreach ($_SESSION['contactlist'] AS $key => $rec)
{
  if (!in_array($rec, $isBefore)) {
    $isBefore[] = $rec;
    echo "<font color=#808080><a href='removecontact.php?contact=" . $_SESSION['recipientlist'][$key] . "&recipient=$rec' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><font color=#808080>" . $rec . "</a></font>";
  }
}
```

So, only unique values are displayed and keys are preserved.